# How to update Apple Watch complications automatically?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

Currently, my code doesn't work. I still have to manually refresh it.
I want the complication to automatically update every 12 hours.

```
func getTimelineStartDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {

    let date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    print("timeline start date :\(date)")
    handler(date)
}

func getTimelineEndDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
    var  date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 2, to: date)!
    print("timeline end date:\(date)")
    handler(date)
}

func getNextRequestedUpdateDate(handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void){
    handler(Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*12))


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data source methods are not implemented. It's needed to be implemented for the refresh.

> At the start of a scheduled update, ClockKit calls either the
>   requestedUpdateDidBegin or requestedUpdateBudgetExhausted method,
>   depending on the state of your complication’s time budget. You must
>   implement one or both of those methods if you want to add data to your
>   timeline. Your implementation of those methods should extend or reload
>   the timeline of your complication as needed. When you do that,
>   ClockKit requests the new timeline entries from your data source. If
>   you do not extend or reload your timeline, ClockKit does not ask for
>   any new timeline entries.

```
func requestedUpdateDidBegin() {
    let server=CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
    for complication in server.activeComplications {
        server.reloadTimelineForComplication(complication)
    }
}
```

For more information check [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/clockkit/clkcomplicationdatasource#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016063-CH1-SW34).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions below to populate your complication with data.

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the current timeline entry
    handler(nil)
}

func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, before date: Date, limit: Int, withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the timeline entries prior to the given date
    handler(nil)
}

func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, after date: Date, limit: Int, withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the timeline entries after to the given date
    handler(nil)
}
```

See the [App Programming Guide for watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ManagingComplications.html)